# Command "locate" in MAC terminal

Tags: macos, shell, locate

I started to study CLI on my computer (iMAC) and reached command **locate**. When I use this command search carried out not in the current directory but everywhere. In addition, this command scans all system and program files but don't scans Downloads or for example in the Music library.

In this regard, I had two questions:

- If I don't specify a search directory where exactly will this command search my file (at root directory or somewhere else)?
- How to specify search directory for this command (for example, I need to find a file that is only in downloads)?

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions. You might try asking on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/), [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) instead.

Answer (score 4):

**The Problem**: You are looking for a Mac cli tool for **optimized searching action** (*search engine indexing*) , the `locate` tool (familiar from unix/linux) is not supported on mac (There's a workaround to enabling it but this is another topic)

**Solution**:  Try `mdfind` terminal command (which is similiar to `locate` command in linux).

(From documentation)  The `mdfind` command consults the central metadata store and returns a list of files that match the given metadata query. The query can be a string or a query expression.

**Example**:

```
/* input: */
mdfind -name configuration.yml

/* output: */    
/Users/someUser/x/y/z/configuration.yml
/Users/someUser/a/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/configuration.yml
/System/Library/someApp/someVersion/someDir/configuration.yml
```

The **optional flags** are:

```
 -0          Prints an ASCII NUL character after each result path.  This is useful when used in conjunction with xargs -0.

 -live       Causes the mdfind command to provide live-updates to the number of files matching the query.  When an update causes the query results to change the number of matches
             is updated.  The find can be cancelled by typing ctrl-C.

 -count      Causes the mdfind command to output the total number of matches, instead of the path to the matching items.

 -onlyin dir
             Limit the scope of the search to the directory specified.

 -name fileName
             Searches for matching file names only.

 -literal    Force the provided query string to be taken as a literal query string, without interpretation.

 -interpret  Force the provided query string to be interpreted as if the user had typed the string into the Spotlight menu.  For example, the string "search" would produce the
             following query string:
                   (* = search* cdw || kMDItemTextContent = search* cdw)
```

Answer (score 0):

As it turned out, on my MAC the Downloads folder for the user "everyone" is generally closed and the system files were open for reading! WOW! After changing the rights and updating the database everything worked as it should. Now the question remains: it was only I who had such default rights?

Answer (score -1):

Try the man page:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/locate.1.html

You might also be interested in `find`:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html

I use find much more than locate, but the answers to your questions are in the docs.

Comment: Yes, typically there's a scheduled job that runs `updatedb` to do that, but they do not show up right away.